# Save the decimal range to the SQL database (Code First)

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Is there any way to store the decimal range in a database? For example, the age range from 24-35, but the goal is to ensure that the user can then enter his age and receive data that are tied to this range.

Maybe there are some tutorials on this topic?

Comment: Why would u want to mention decimal range in this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a table with the minimum and the maximum for the range, something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE age_range
             (minimum integer,
              maximum integer,
              name AS convert(varchar, minimum) + '-' + convert(varchar, maximum),
              PRIMARY KEY (minimum,
                           maximum),
              CHECK (minimum <= maximum));
```

Maybe also add a trigger checking, that ranges don't overlap, if this of any concern.

You can than select the range(s) an age is in with something like:

```
SELECT *
       FROM age_range
       WHERE minimum <= @user_age
             AND maximum >= @user_age;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd077/4)

Answer (score 1):

In an sql table there is no easy way to store ranges in one field. You will need two fields: `[AgeFrom] int, [AgeTo] int`.

There would be a possible solution to store a range in a string (varchar) field and to parse the stored range information e.g. '24-35', but this is much more complex compared with the two field solution.

Anyway you can define an object in C# to determinate if a given age is in which specific range and return the desired datas.